# Android Geocoder such ad google maps

Tags: android, mkreversegeocoder

With android Geocoder  I can find a shop such as Google Maps or I can only search street, monuments, airport, etc ?? I want to search shopping center with name...

Comment: Be more constructive with you question, share what you have done, or if you have not done anything at all then share what you have in mind to do.

Comment: I want to create a activty where I can write "shopping center" and it search on the mapview with geocoder.getFromLocation all shoopping center into my zone. But, if I put "shopping center" into search box the address list is empty this is the code

list = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitudine, longitudine, 1);address = list.get(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on the internet for examples for GeoCoding.

But this is what I suggest:

You can make a use of `Google Places API`, which allows you to search location within some radius by specifying the `type` which is what you are looking.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests

All you have to do is to parse the output of the URL as it is specified, using `JSON` (parse the latitude and longitude and the name of the building) or `XML`. and show the overlays on the map.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html

Here is the list of types you can search for.